# How to setup build.phonegap.com with config.xml?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using build.phonegap.com to build my html/css/js bundle into a mobile for iOS and Android. I want to include several plugins using config.xml, but I could not find out how to set this up in phonegap.

Any one can help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

There you will see a list of all the available plugins. Once you find one you want, click on the name and it will take you to a page that explains the setup. (typically just copy the xml string provided and paste it into your config.xml).